# Firewalld says a port is open, but nmap says its closed

Tags: centos, smtp, firewalld

On my CentOS 7 install I'm having trouble connecting one of my email accounts made on the server as an alias on Gmail.

I have run the following commands:

```
 firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=smtp
 firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=25/tcp
```

And when I do a

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --query-port=25/tcp
```

It returns 'yes'

However I still get a 'server cannot be reached' error on Gmail and on various email testing sites.

I then did a

```
nmap -sT -O localhost
```

And saw my ports weren't listed there. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First, with firewalld, you need to reload after you apply permanent rules using `firewall-cmd --reload` or `--complete-reload`. Reverify your query or `firewall-cmd --list-all`.

Second, if you did do the above already, check `ss -tuna | grep 25` and see if it's listening on `*:25`. If it's listening on '127.0.0.1:25`, then you need to reconfigure postfix to listen on another interface. Example.

```
inet_interfaces = $myhostname
# or...
inet_interfaces = all
```

Comment: When I do `ss -nlput | grep 25` it doesn't show anything. It should be set up with my Plesk installation?

Comment: I do not know how plesk works. You need at least postfix running and listening on port 25.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have three device interfaces: lo, LAN and WAN.

- lo, localhost  127.0.0.1
- LAN, Local Area Network  192.168.1.2
- WAN, World Area Network  169.254.8.8

If you open traffic from WAN, assuming zone public in your post, it has to be directed. This is called a source and a destination.

Outside comes by WAN so source is unknown, so we can allow all: 0.0.0.0

Our mail server is running on the LAN, so perhaps more servers can easy use it locally. (If firewall allows it). To reach it from the outside we need to define the destination.

source = 0.0.0.0, destination=192.168.1.2 on port 25. Ports also have a source port and a destination port.

```
0.0.0.0:25 -> 192.168.1.2:25
```

For an outsider it looks like this:

```
my.ip.address -> 169.254.8.8:25
```

Now the question is, is there somebody at the end of the tunnel? It could be that you setup your mail server on lo (127.0.0.1).

To check ports you can run `netstat -al`.

- -a or --all shows all sockets currently in use
- -l or --listening shows only the sockets currently listening for incoming connection.

I assume plesk is a virtual hosting provider, often those have a firewall layer on top of the instance. Do not configure the firewall on the instance itself then, but rather at the top layer.

I have no experience with plesk, but check out their F.A.Q.